# signed electron app shell.openItem() fails

Tags: macos, electron

I want my Electron app could open *.txt-files (generated by my app) with system default application (default text editor).

I use `shell.openItem(path)` to perform it - and it worked fine... until I've packed (mas) and signed the app. I suppose I have to add some entitlements when signing, but already tried bunch of them without success :(

Could anyone give me a hand with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately Electron disables the `shell.openItem()` API in Mac App Store builds. From their [signing guide](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide.md#shellopenitemfilepath):

> [`shell.openItem()`] will fail when the app is signed for distribution in the Mac App Store. Subscribe to [#9005](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9005) for updates.

---

However, there is a work-around that will enable you to have the same functionality:

```
shell.openExternal('file://' + myFilePath);
```

This approach is also confirmed to pass the Apple Store Reviews ([see here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9005#issuecomment-313493809)).